# Wrapper for stored procedures to use as SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I currently have all the SQL code on the code pages for `SqlDatasource`'s on my gridviews.

My thinking was since the code behind pages are on the server that would be safe but I've been told this is still subject to attacks and I should migrate to stored procedures and use a wrapper to call them.

Transferring the SQL to stored procedures isn't a problem but I have no idea how to create a wrapper for them.

I would like to have the update delete and select for each source in one stored procedure so as not to have dozens of stored procedures so I figure using a mode (int) parameter I can send in then use the correct query using if statements.

if this is the right approach then I just need help with the wrapper if not can anyone advise the best way to do this whilst not having 3/4 stored procedures for each `SqlDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

you do not mention it explicitly but i suppose you create sql code on the fly: the issue there is [sql injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

using stored procedures you avoid it completely because you use parameters; you could use parameters for plain sql code also but stored procedures are usually preferred. the first few reason that comes to mind: sql code is on database, separate from frontend (on a different layer), can be changed/fixed/updated/upgraded without changing the frontend.

in the code behind the wrapper is the `SqlDatasource` for stored procedure as it is for plain sql code.
if you set the `*CommandType` to the value `StoredProcedure` you're done.

about the 'issue' with multiple stored procedures i think that may be a matter of taste; imho is better to have simple stored procedures that handle a single operation.
easier maintenance, improved readability, less chance to have difficult-to-debug bugs.

Comment: Yea I pretty much create the Sql as needed, Crowcoder and yourself has said its not good putting all in one SP but surely having one SP per Source is much easier to manage then a massive list of Sp's you have to search through to get the one you want?

Comment: @user3652973 think about c#: why you split the code in classes and objects? the same answer is valid for sql code: you don't have classes but sp, function & the like. low number of objects != easy maintenance/debug. when you write sql code if you add complexity to the objects the debug time is likely to raise even for trivial glitches.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to always let someone else do it. ORMs like the Entity Framework are great. Or you can use the Data Access Application Block from the [Enterprise Library.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx)
But do not put insert/update/delete in one stored procedure. That is bad practice.